# How can I call GetProcessHandleFromHwnd in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, winapi

How can I call GetProcessHandleFromHwnd in Delphi 7?

Apparently it is an XP-introduced Windows API function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318087(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just like any other function ;) The import is [`here`](http://pastebin.com/uXAiErvE).

Comment: Do a websearch for oleacc.pas

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call the function directly. But you can make a reference:

```
// reference to the Windows function:
function GetProcessHandleFromHwnd(hwnd: HWND): THandle; external 'oleacc.dll' name 'GetProcessHandleFromHwnd'; stdcall;

// and you can call it from your own function:
function TryGetProcessHandle(const WindowHandle: THandle; var ProcessHandle: THandle): Boolean;
begin
  ProcessHandle := GetProcessHandleFromHwnd(WindowHandle);
  Result := (ProcessHandle <> 0);
end;
```

Comment: GetProcessHandleFromHwnd should be `stdcall` and why can you not call it directly?

Comment: You cannot call GetProcessHandleFromHwnd directly in Delphi, I think. The function is in Oleacc.dll, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/getprocesshandlefromhwnd - so I included WinApi.Oleacc, but the function is not referenced in that unit.