# How can I call GetWindowThreadProcessId in Delphi 10.2?

Tags: delphi, winapi

How can I call GetWindowThreadProcessId in Delphi 10.2?

It is [Windows API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318087(v=vs.85).aspx).

I found [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928391/how-can-i-call-getprocesshandlefromhwnd-in-delphi-7) dealing with this topic in Delphi 7. I would like to ask if there is any change since Delphi 7? (Actual version Delphi 10.2)

I would prefer to call Delphi function from its winapi instead of including oleacc.dll.

Comment: Its used in TApplication.IsKeyMsg and declared in Windows in Tokyo

Comment: @FredS, so as could be in Delphi 7. The linked question is about a different function.

Comment: @Victoria, so two questions in one :)

Comment: @FredS, hard to say :) If this is about `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd`, nothing changed (import is not in Tokyo). If it's about `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, then its import is in available in Tokyo (and might have been in Delphi 7 as well).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the question is clearly about `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd()`, not about `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. That is why I edited the question the way I did. Why did you revert it?

Comment: @Remy Because it asks twice about `GetWindowThreadProcessId` (in the title and the body) and states a preference to avoid leaning on `oleacc.dll`. Plus I had already written an answer to the original question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Obviously the title and body were typos. `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` is not in `oleacc.dll`, but `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd()` is, and both links are about `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd()`.

Comment: Maybe. But the right thing to do anyway is to ignore `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd` and call `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, as you well know

Comment: You change text of my question so that makes no sense to ask. Then you downvote my question, I do not get that....

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special here. You need to use the `Winapi.Windows` unit which declares the `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, and the you can call the function. That's it.

The links you provide refer to a different function, `GetProcessHandleFromHwnd`. This is a convenience function that is equivalent to calling `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to obtain the process ID, and then calling `OpenProcess` to obtain the process handle.

However, this convenience method does not allow you to specify access rights. The process handle is requested with `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE`. If those aren't what you need then this function is no use to you. A further limitation is that the convenience function only succeeds if the target process is running under the same user as the calling process. So I would suggest that you call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and then `OpenProcess` specifying the access rights that you need.